# How to cluster the elements of a list based on connectivity?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, cluster-analysis

Consider a list (`coordpairs`) of coordinate pairs as

```
np = 4;
coordpairs = Cases[Subsets[Tuples[Range[np],{2}],{2}], {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} /; 
                   Abs[c - a] < 2 && Abs[d - b] < 2];
```

and their corresponding connectivities (`conn`) as

**Edit 2: (corrected connectivity)**

```
conn = {1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.,
        0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
        0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.};
```

`1` indicates that there exists a path between the two points and `0` otherwise.

Now I wish to find all the paths (specifically, the coordinates of the points through the paths). For example, the first group will consist of the coordinates

> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 
>     1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}}

Second group:

> {{3, 4}, {4, 4}, {4, 3}, {4, 2}, {4, 1}}

**Edit 1** These two groups are visualized in the image below:

[image]

How can I do this?

**Edit 3:(for higher `np` values)**

Both the answers work well for `np = 4`. However, for `np = 8`

I have,

> Length@coordpairs = 210;
>
> conn = {0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 
>   1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 
>   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 
>   0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
>   0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 
>   1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 
>   0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 
>   0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 
>   0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 
>   0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
>   1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 
>   0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
>   1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.};

Now

```
 comps = ConnectedComponents[
  UndirectedEdge @@@ Extract[coordpairs, Position[db, 1.]]];
```

gives me `4` connected components where

```
Length@comps[[1]] + Length@comps[[2]] + Length@comps[[3]] + 
 Length@comps[[4]]
```

results

> 62

while it should be `64`. The two missing coordinates are

> {{1, 2}, {6, 3}}

where is it going wrong?

Comment: Do you mean `ConnectedComponents[UndirectedEdge @@@ Extract[coordpairs, Position[conn, 1.]]]`?

Comment: @Coolwater No. It lists down all the coordinates. It does not group as I have mentioned.

Comment: I do not understand the question.  "I wish to find all the paths."  What is a "path"?  The graph you describe looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vyeqy.png) and has one connected component.  What do you mean by "group"?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have corrected the connectivity list.

Comment: @Coolwater I am sorry, it was a mistake on my part and now your code gives me the result I want.

Comment: You get 62, because only the edges are passed to `ConnectedComponents`. There are two vertices with no connections which are themselves additional components. See Szabolcs' answer where a graph object is passed such that `ConnectedComponents` includes these.

Answer (score 3):

I'm agree [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170919/how-to-cluster-the-elements-of-a-list-based-on-connectivity#comment449266_170919). This is your graph as you say

```
g = Graph[MapThread[
    If[#2 == 1, UndirectedEdge @@ #, Nothing @@ #] &, {coordpairs, conn}]];
Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> VertexList[g], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

> [image]

I also think your graph just have one connected component. You can *group* those connected vertices by `ConnectedComponents` and `ConnectedGraphComponents`

Comment: Sorry for the mistake on my part. I have corrected the connectivity accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
vertices = Union@Catenate[coordpairs];

edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ Pick[coordpairs, conn, 1.];

graph = Graph[vertices, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vertices, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ConnectedComponents[graph]
(* {{{3, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 1}, {1,
    4}, {2, 4}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 4}, {4, 3}, {4, 2}, {4, 
   1}}} *)
```